# What was The British Ministry of Magic like under Pius Thicknesse?

Tags: harry-potter, ministry-of-magic

What was happening at the Ministry of Magic during Pius Thicknesse's time as Minister?

We know from the trio's trip to acquire Tom Riddle's Locket from Dolores Umbridge during the Horcrux Hunt that it had indeed turned gloomy, and that a strict pure and half-blood regime was in place, and muggle-borns were being pursued, but what agenda were they pursuing? Were they publicly still at war with Lord Voldemort and were they still in pursuit of alleged Death Eaters publicly?

What were they telling the public? We know the Order knew what was really happening but I want to know what the general wizarding community besides the Order of The Phoenix and Death Eaters knew.

Comment: This question does not seem to be too broad.

Answer (score 2):

I think lots of people knew Voldemort and his supporters had taken over but with the Daily Prophet toeing the official line most people were not sure about what was happening.

> “So Death Eaters have taken over the *Daily Prophet* too?” asked Hermione furiously.
>
> Lupin nodded.
>
> “But surely people realize what’s going on?”
>
> “The coup has been smooth and virtually silent,” said Lupin. “The official version of Scrimgeour’s murder is that he resigned; he has been replaced by Pius Thicknesse, who is under the Imperius Curse.”
>
> “Why didn’t Voldemort declare himself Minister for Magic?” asked Ron.
>
> Lupin laughed.
>
> “He doesn’t need to, Ron. Effectively he *is* the Minister, but why should
>   he sit behind a desk at the Ministry? His puppet, Thicknesse, is taking care of everyday business, leaving Voldemort free to extend his power beyond the Ministry.
>
> “Naturally many people have deduced what has happened: there has been such a dramatic change in Ministry policy in the last few days, and many are whispering that Voldemort must be behind it. However, that is the point: they whisper. They daren’t confide in each other, not knowing whom to trust; they are scared to speak out, in case their suspicions are true and their families are targeted. Yes, Voldemort is playing a very clever game. Declaring himself might have provoked open rebellion: remaining masked has created confusion, uncertainty, and fear.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11, The Bribe*</sup></sub>

Ministry used (lame) propaganda to commit genocide on muggle-borns.

> “Muggle-born Register,” she read aloud, “The Ministry of Magic is undertaking a survey of so-called ‘Muggle-borns’, the better to understand how they came to possess magical secrets."
>
> “Recent research undertaken by the Department of Mysteries reveals that magic can only be passed from person to person when wizards reproduce. Where no proven wizarding ancestry exists, therefore, the so-called Muggle-born is likely to have obtained magical power by theft or force."
>
> “The Ministry is determined to root out such usurpers of magical power, and to this end has issued an invitation to every so-called Muggle-born to present themselves for interview by the newly appointed Muggle-born Registration Commission.”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11, The Bribe*</sup></sub>

Some people might have accepted the propaganda but mostly people were scared and with Dumbledore and Harry out of picture there was nobody for them to rally around.

> “And this dramatic change in Ministry policy,” said Harry, “involves warning the wizarding world against me instead of Voldemort?”
>
> “That’s certainly part of it,” said Lupin, “and it is a masterstroke. Now that Dumbledore is dead, you — the Boy Who Lived — were sure to be the symbol and rallying point for any resistance to Voldemort. But by suggesting that you had a hand in the old hero’s death, Voldemort has not only set a price upon your head, but sown doubt and fear amongst many who would have defended you.
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 11, The Bribe*</sup></sub>

There was only one radio program which was telling the truth about events that were occurring.

> “*Potterwatch*, didn’t I tell you that’s what it was called? The programme I keep trying to get on the radio, the only one that tells the truth about what’s going on! Nearly all the programmes are following You-Know-Who’s line, all except *Potterwatch*. I really want you to hear it, but it’s tricky tuning in …”
>
> <sub><sup>*Harry Potter and the Deathly Hallows, Chapter 22, The Deathly Hallows*</sup></sub>

We have seen in the previous books that people blindly put their trust in the Ministry of Magic and the Daily Prophet.

With limited information available to the general public, they would not have known what exactly was happening. All they would have known was that the ministry was trying to purge muggle-born wizards who had stolen magic. They might not have believed in it but there were no other source of news.